# How to insert dynamic country state city dropdown in php? This code insert only their id

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, insert, dropdown

**This is js**

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.4.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function()
    {
        $("#loding1").hide();
        $("#loding2").hide();
        $(".state").change(function()
        {
            $("#loding1").show();
            var id=$(this).val();
            var dataString = 'id='+ id;
            $(".district").find('option').remove();
            $(".area").find('option').remove();
            $.ajax
            ({
                type: "POST",
                url: "get_district.php",
                data: dataString,
                cache: false,
                success: function(html)
                {
                    $("#loding1").hide();
                    $(".district").html(html);
                } 
            });
        });


        $(".district").change(function()
        {
            $("#loding2").show();
            var id=$(this).val();
            var dataString = 'id='+ id;

            $.ajax
            ({
                type: "POST",
                url: "get_area.php",
                data: dataString,
                cache: false,
                success: function(html)
                {
                    $("#loding2").hide();
                    $(".area").html(html);
                } 
            });
        });

    });
    </script>
```

**This is index.php**
Here I can select state-district-area dynamically from DB. But when I am inserting this insert only their relative id. But I want to insert state_name,district_name,area_name. Is there any to help me.

```
<div class="form-control">
<form name="form2" action="" method="post" onSubmit="return valid2();">
 <label for="email">State :</label>
<select name="state" class="state">
<option selected="selected">--Select State--</option>
<?php
    $stmt = $DB_con->prepare("SELECT * FROM state");
    $stmt->execute();
    while($row=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
    {
        ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $row['state_id']; ?>"><?php echo $row['state_name']; ?></option>
        <?php
    } 
?>
</select>

<label>District :</label> <select name="district" class="district">
<option selected="selected">--Select District--</option>
</select>
<img src="ajax-loader.gif" id="loding1"></img>
<label>Area :</label> <select name="area" class="area">
<option selected="selected">--Select Area--</option>
</select>
<img src="ajax-loader.gif" id="loding2"></img>

</div>
</div>
 <input type="submit" name="registration" class="btn btn-primary" value="Registration"/>
</form>

</div>
```

**This is get_district.php**

```
<?php
include('dbconfig.php');
if($_POST['id'])
{
    $id=$_POST['id'];

    $stmt = $DB_con->prepare("SELECT * FROM district_table WHERE state_id=:id");
    $stmt->execute(array(':id' => $id));
    ?><option selected="selected">Select District :</option><?php
    while($row=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
    {
        ?>
            <option value="<?php echo $row['district_id']; ?>"><?php echo $row['district_name']; ?></option>
        <?php
    }
}
?>
```

**This is get_area.php**

```
<?php
include('dbconfig.php');
if($_POST['id'])
{
    $id=$_POST['id'];

    $stmt = $DB_con->prepare("SELECT * FROM area_table WHERE district_id=:id");
    $stmt->execute(array(':id' => $id));
    ?><option selected="selected">Select Area :</option>
    <?php while($row=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
    {
        ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $row['are_id']; ?>"><?php echo $row['area_name']; ?></option>
        <?php
    }
}
?>
```

I want to insert state_name,district_name,area_name in DB. But the above code is inserting their id. Please Help me.

Comment: That's because the value in the dropdown is the ID. Either set the value to the `district_name`, or do a lookup when inserting.

Comment: Though, in most cases, it is a good thing to only insert their IDs. If you change the name of a state, for example, you will now have to change it in several places.

Comment: In the database there are 3 tables of state, city and area. These 3 tables are fully loaded. Now I am selecting these state, city and area for inserting into the other table. The problem is that it inserts only their ID. I know there is a mistake in Javascript. Because when I changed the option value = state_name. The dropdown is not working.